# Does Flex fire an event after a chart is rendered in UI?

Tags: apache-flex

I am looking for an event which is fired (if any) after a chart is rendered (visible in UI) in Flash, we are using Flex SDK 3.0. We have to capture the screenshot after the chart is rendered, current implementation adds a huge delay in update_complete event callback, this is slowing down the whole job of generating images.

I tried to use EXIT_FRAME event, but this doesn't seem to serve the purpose. Any help to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Dan

Comment: I would have told you to use updateComplete; which follows the standard Flex component conventions.  Can you specify which chart you are using? Perhaps the issue is with your code to generate the screenshot?  It seems that code would be a bottleneck no matter which event you trigger it from.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe use this event : mx.events.FlexEvent.TRANSFORM_CHANGE

But if you want to use it, you are obligate to inherit from Chart Component classes. Take a look at  DataTransform Class.

http://help.adobe.com/es_ES/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/chartClasses/DataTransform.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at the [DisplayObject liveDoc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#eventSummary), where there are several types of events. Some are fired before the rendering (Event.RENDER), some are fired after specific operation (ResizeEvent, for instance). But if you really want to know when you chart has been rendered, why don't you **watch for the validation methods** (updateDisplayList(), commitProperties()) by overriding them in a child class and fire a custom event in there ?

Comment: updateDisplayList() and commitProperties() are fired before the chart is rendered, I couldn't find an event which is fired after the chart is rendered, something like POST_RENDER or AFTER_RENDER kind of event.